# Docker unable to perform login against SSO / Federation Services via Apache & Shibboleth modules

Tags: apache, single-sign-on, docker, saml-2.0, shibboleth

I have a private Docker registry sitting behind a secure instance of Apache / Ubuntu in Amazon cloud. Apache handles the corporate authentication via Shibboleth module (single-sign-on). So, using a web browser, there is no issue in searching and deleting container images in the registry after successful authentication. However, the command "docker login https://some.domain" including username, password and email from a different server just hangs and does not respond. Unfortunately, Apache, docker registry and shibboleth logs are not very helpful either even in debug mode.

I will be very keen to hear from anyone who has experience in securing a private docker registry via Apache & shibboleth where corporate enterprise IDs and SSO are required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shibboleth authentication via the Apache mod_shib module requires redirecting the end-user back to their home Identity Provider (IdP) where they will then be redirected back to the application's Service Provider (SP) with a valid session. This is a great pattern for fully-web-based applications, but this model can't be applied to command-line applications or applications that can't follow this model of web-based redirection.

Comment: Thanks. That explains a lot. I have now turned off Shibboleth auth and instead implemented Apache basic auth. As a result, docker pull from a command-line tool is working as expected. However, having to maintain a password file is not ideal where there is a large number of user base for docker registries. Is there an alternative security model/pattern where security is delegated to something else and that works well with Docker pull command?

Comment: @Shahzad: The obvious alternative would be to use OAuth2. You login at your IDP and get a token that is used for accessing docker. You can decide how long the token is valid and can revoke it as well.